# multinomial logistic regression with preceding factor analysis

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model, factor-analysis, multinomial-distribution

Currently I am planning to analyze a large dataset containing nominal, ordinal as well as ratio variables using R. My goal is to predict the outcome of a certain variable X (nominal, ordinal or ratio) using all the other variables I have in the dataset (100+). 
So far I came up with the following plan:

- to reduce the size of the dataset and prevent to get too many predicting variables, I would first run a latent factor analysis to extract certain factors correlating with the outcome (see: http://web.archive.org/web/20130502181643/http://www.statisticalinnovations.com/articles/bozdogan.pdf or http://factominer.free.fr/)
- depending on the scale of the dependent variable, I would either run a (multinomial) logistic regression, an ordinal logistic regression or a GLM if the dv is a ratio (see: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/1190/type-of-regression-with-nominal-ordinal-interval-and-ratio-data) with the extracted factors of step one

Do you think that I am on the right track? Is the latent factor analysis the right choice to extract the most important factors or are there better methods? Are the any restrictions to using the proposed regression methods with a preceding factor analysis?

Comment: 1st step is "feature selection". Your methods sounds reasonable. You can also consider PCA (principal component analysis) or obtaining variable importance after a random forest. 
2nd step is modelling using the variables from step 1. You can chose some appropriate models based on the type of variable you want to model, as you mentioned. You can chose the best model using cross validation methods.

Comment: As I am quite new to the processes of data mining, I really want to stick to a - more or less - easy model. As a measure of feature selection, I actually planned on doing the latent factor analysis. Thus, I should be able to reduce the size of the dataset to the variables loading on a reasonable size of probably predicting factors. One problem, I came across, is how to calculate a value for the different factors -> how do I combine the values of mixed scale variables in order to get a value to predict the outcome variable in the modeling? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: There should be a way to obtain the scores of your new variables (factors) via the factor analysis command. As an example see this: `dt = mtcars;
f = factanal(dt, factors=5, scores = "regression");
dt = cbind(dt, f$scores)`. It creates 5 new variables and uses a given method to calculate the scores of those new variables. For more info see `?factanal`.

Comment: Sounds perfectly logic, the PCA calculated by the FactoMineR package as well gives out scores (principal coordinates) which seem to be suitable for feeding them into a subsequent regression model - aren't they? Thank you very much, I really appreciate your comments.

Comment: Yes, you can use those scores as your new variables. Just make sure everything is OK up to that point. Mainly check  (a) if you've picked a reasonable number of components and (b)  whether you need to normalize your original variables before doing the PCA, if they are measured in different scales.